# Como poner una imagen desde una variable en el bocadillo de Market de Gooble Maps

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview

Tengo creado en un Fragment una opción onClick(View v) que dependiendo de lo que se seleccione pasa un dato diferente.

Clase Fragment **Datos.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),GPS.class);
            intent.putExtra("dato1","Fumanchu1");
            intent.putExtra("dato2","Fumanchu2");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Clase FragmentActivity **GPS.java**

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    latitud = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("latitud"));
    longitud = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("longitud"));
    tvDatos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDatos);
    tvDatos.setText(String.valueOf(latitud)+","+String.valueOf(latitud));

    int imagenMarcador = extras.getInt("dato3");
    imageview.setImageResource(imagenMarcador);
```

Lo que intento es pasar una imagen PNG de Datos.java a GPS.java para que se muestre en el bocadillo al pulsar en el market, junto con .title y snippet.

Lo que tengo creado en un adaptador para definir un bocadillo diferente al que por defecto se mostraría al hacer clip en el marcador.

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new  UserInfoWindowsAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
```

**UserInfoWindowsAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    View infoWindows=inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_info_windows, null);

    Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
    int imagenMarcador = datos.getInt("dato3");

    TextView title = (TextView)infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView description = (TextView)infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    title.setText(marker.getTitle());
    description.setText(marker.getSnippet());
    //imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.school);
    imageview.setImageResource(imagenMarcador);
    return(infoWindows);
}
}
```

**user_info_windows.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imagen_prueba" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#002AFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#F57CF2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se muestre la imagen que yo diga en el bocadillo del marcador?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Hola socu a que te refieres con el "bocadillo" ?

Comment: He editado el post de arriba para poner una imagen, esa información que se muestra al pulsar en el market he visto en videos que lo llaman bocadillo,

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas enviar la imagen, si esta se encuentra en tus recursos simplemente definela en el `ImageView`:

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
```

Ejemplo:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    View infoWindows=inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_info_windows, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView description = (TextView)infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)infoWindows.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    title.setText(marker.getTitle());
    description.setText(marker.getSnippet());
    //Define imagen que se encuentra en /Drawable
    imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);

    return(infoWindows);
}
```

---

Si deseas enviar que imagen deseas agregar, puedes enviar el valor entero del recurso y este usarlo en el `ImageView`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),GPS.class);
...
...            
intent.putExtra("dato3", R.id.puente);
startActivity(intent);
```

en la `Activity` que recibe la información, obtén el valor entero y asignalo a el `ImageView`:

```
Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
int imagenMarcador = datos.getInt("dato3");

...
...
   //Define imagen que se encuentra en /Drawable
   imageview.setImageResource(imagenMarcador);
```

Comment: Pero de esa forma siempre se mostraría la misma imagen, lo que quiero es que dependiendo de lo que se escoja en la clase **Datos.java** se muestre una imagen diferente, lo que pienso es que no hace falta enviar la imagen, sino un texto `intent.putExtra("dato3","puente")` y que muestre la imagen de un puente, lo que no se es como programar eso, se tendria que enviar el `intent.putExtra("dato3","puente")` al activity **UserInfoWindowsAdapter** desde **GPS.java** y ahí ver que texto es para mostrar esa imagen, pero no se como hacerlo, si es que eso se puede hacer.

Comment: La imagen se encontraría en tu proyecto?

Comment: si en la carpeta **drawable**

Comment: Puedes enviar el valor int del recurso, revisa la actualización.

Comment: me tira este mensaje de error en getIntent() http://funkyimg.com/i/2Rvew.png

Comment: @SoCu la obtencion de los datos del bundle se realiza en onCreate(), imagenMarcador  declarala como variable de clase.

Comment: La clase UserInfoWindowsAdapter.java no tiene onCreate(), te he puesto el codigo completo en el primer post,

Comment: si hay que hacerlo en la clase **GPS.java** dentro de este `onCreate()`, lo que te comentaba antes es que no se como pasar ese valor dentro de **UserInfoWindowsAdapter.java** por cierto `intent.putExtra("dato3", R.id.puente)` puede que sea `"R.drawable.puente"` y este entre comillas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89930/discussion-between-elenasys-and-socu).